# SQL: Use of with-clause in "not in"-operator

Tags: sql

is it possible to realize something like this?

```
WITH subQ(attr1) as (SELECT attr1 FROM tab1)

SELECT tab2.attr2,  FROM tab2

where tab2.attr2 not in subQ
```

I don't want to write the subselect after the "not in".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper SQL uses a subquery:

```
WITH subQ(attr1) as (
      SELECT attr1
      FROM tab1
     )
SELECT tab2.attr2
FROM tab2
where tab2.attr2 not in (select attr1 from subQ);
```

The CTE is treated as a table alias, so it should be referenced from a `from` clause.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer `NOT EXISTS` instead which is clearer and less error-prone:

```
WITH CTE as 
(
    SELECT attr1 FROM tab1
)
SELECT tab2.attr2 FROM tab2
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM CTE WHERE CTE.tab1=tab2.attr2
)
```

However, i don't see the need for the CTE at all.

[**Should I use NOT IN, OUTER APPLY, LEFT OUTER JOIN, EXCEPT, or NOT EXISTS?**](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join#sthash.dE6bvP5l.dpbs)

Answer (score 0):

```
with subQ(attr1) as
(
    SELECT attr1 FROM tab1
)
SELECT tab2.attr2
FROM tab2
intersect
select tab2.attr1 from subQ
```